# How come we have to dereference the pointer returned from strbrk(), but don't have to derefence the pointer returned from strrchr()?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, string.h, strrchr

How come we have to dereference the pointer returned from strbrk(), but don't have to derefence the pointer returned from strrchr()?

So I have the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void){
    const char *string1 = "This is a test";
    const char *string2 = "beware";
    printf( "%s\"%s\"\n'%c'%s\n\"%s\"\n", "Of the characters in ", string2,
            *strpbrk( string1, string2 ),
            " appears earliest in ", string1 );
    /// How come for the above example we had to dereference the pointer returned from strbrk()
    ///Below we didn't have to derefence the pointer returned from strrchr() and so we didn't have to
    /// put * in front of the function to dereference it.

    puts("");
    const char *stringg1 = "A zoo has many animals including zebras";
    int c = 'z';
    printf( "%s\n%s'%c'%s\"%s\"\n",
            "The remainder of string1 beginning with the",
            "last occurrence of character ", c,
            " is: ", strrchr(stringg1, c));

}
```

The output is:

```
Of the characters in "beware"
'a' appears earliest in 
"This is a test"

The remainder of string1 beginning with the
last occurrence of character 'z' is: "zebras"
```

My question is why do we have to dereference the pointer in a function like strpbrk() and use *, for it to work properly, but for the bottom bit of code that gets the last occurrence of a string, we don't have to dereference it and use *. In fact, if we dereference strrchr() it causes an error and for the program to crash. From my understanding, strrchr() returns a pointer, so to access the value store in the pointer location, we have to dereference it no?

I read another post and think it may have something to do with the fact that in the top portion, where I use strpbrk() I am only printing a character, whereas in the bottom portion I'm printing a string. If this is the cause, can someone explain why?

I am learning C so please answer using beginner words.

Comment: The two functions _both_ return a `char *`. But, for the first `printf` you use `%c` and the second uses `%s`. So, to change a `char *` to a `char` you have to dereference it to be compatible with `%c`. The two `printf` statements use the functions in different ways. So, the test isn't entirely valid. Try reversing the use of the functions to see what happens.

Comment: Tip: It's weird to use `%s` to insert a constant string instead of just including the string in the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `strbrk` and `strchr` since both return a string. It has to do with `%s` vs `%c`.

You wanted to print the entire string returned by `strbrk`, so you used `%s` and provided (a pointer to) the string.

You wanted to print the first character of the string returned by `strbrk`, so you used `%c` and provided the first character of the string returned by `strbrk` (`*p` ≡ `*( p + 0 )` ≡ `p[0]`).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) {
   const char *s = "The brown fox jumped";

   printf( "%c\n", *strpbrk( s, "jf" ) );   // f
   printf( "%s\n", strpbrk( s, "jf" ) );    // fox jumped

   printf( "%c\n", *strchr( s, 'e' ) );     // e
   printf( "%s\n", strchr( s, 'e' ) );      // e brown fox jumped

   printf( "%c\n", *strrchr( s, 'e' ) );    // e
   printf( "%s\n", strrchr( s, 'e' ) );     // ed
}
```

Note the blindly dereferencing the result of these functions is unsafe since they can return `NULL`. It's also unsafe to blindly provide the value returned by these to `%s` for the same reason.

Comment: `%c` expects an `int` though perhaps that would confuse the noobs.

Comment: @Ian Abbott, Since you're splitting hairs, `%c` expects an `unsigned char` provided as an `int`. Anyway, "expects a `char`" is no longer found in my answer.